# QString split in Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, split, qstring, qt5.6

```
QString strTest = "SHUT\nDOWN";
QStringList slstLines = strTest.split("\n");
```

In the above example I would expect the String list to contain two entries, but it only contains 1, which is the same as the strTest...why isn't split working?

I've also tried:

```
QStringList slstLines = strText.split(QRegExp("[\n]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
    QStringList slstLines = strTest.split("\\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:
for example [`split`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split):

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
...
QString str = "SHUT\nDOWN";
QStringList list = str.split("\n");
qDebug() << list;
//output: ("SHUT", "DOWN")
```

/////

```
QString str = "a\n\nb,\n";

QStringList list1 = str.split("\n");
// list1: [ "a", "", "b", "c" ]

QStringList list2 = str.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
// list2: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```